# Wait for ajax return while in loop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been struggling to get this to work using the `$.Deferred` object.  Here is the stubbed setup.

```
g_plans = [];

$(function(){
   // I have to use a custom ajax function, but it returns a promise obj
    var pageLoadPromise.ajax{(
        url: //call to webmethod
    });

    pageLoadPromise.done(matrix.buildGrid);

    ...
});

(function(matrix,$,undefined){

    var matrix.buildGrid = function(components){
        var gridData = data.d.components;
        buildHeader(gridData);
        buildRows(gridData);
    };

    function buildHeader(components){
            $.each(components,function(key,component){
                //does some stuff
                if(this === that){
                   //do some other stuff
                }
                else{
                    getPlans(copmonent.COMPONENT_ID);
                    //does other stuff
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function buildRows(components){
        //does stuff, but uses data from getPlans
    }

    function getPlans(component){
        var planPromise = ajax({
            url: //call to webmethod
            data:{ componentId:component}
        planPromise.done(function(data){
          g_plans.push({componentId:componentId,plans:data.d.plans});
        });
    }
})(window.matrix = window.matrix || {}, jQuery);
```

The problem is `buildRows` starts before the `getPlans` has time to finish it's ajax call, which is causing my issue.  I have tried a few things with no success.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the easiest solution I can see:

1) Have `getPlans()` return the `planPromise` promise, which can then be handled back in the `buildHeader()` function.

```
function getPlans(component) {
    var planPromise = ajax({
        url: //call to webmethod
        data:{ componentId:component}
    });
    planPromise.done(function(data) {
        g_plans.push({componentId: data.componentId, plans: data.d.plans});
    });
    return planPromise; // return the promise!
}
```

2) Call `buildRows()` from the `buildHeader()` function instead of `matrix.buildgrid` using the promise returned from `getPlans()`.

```
function buildHeader(components) {
    var lastPromise;
    $.each(components, function (key, component) {
        lastPromise = getPlans(component.COMPONENT_ID);
    });
    lastPromise.done(function() {
        buildRows(components);
    });
}
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/tbek9owt/) illustrating the basic idea.

The second step is unnecessary, I just found it easier.  The other option would be to return the `lastPromise` from `buildHeader()`, and handle it back in `matrix.buildgrid`.

```
var matrix.buildgrid = function(components) {
    var gridData = components;
    var lastPromise = buildHeader(gridData);
    lastPromise.done(function() {
        buildRows(components);
    });
};

function buildHeader(components) {
    var lastPromise;
    $.each(components, function (key, component) {
        lastPromise = getPlans(component.COMPONENT_ID);
    });
    return lastPromise;
}
```

EDIT:

To handle the case of `lastPromise` never getting set as a promise, you'd have to do something like this:

```
if (lastPromise && typeof lastPromise === 'object') {
    lastPromise.done(function() {
        buildRows(components);
    });
} else {
    buildRows(components); // or whatever needs to happen here.
}
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/tbek9owt/1/) including that bit in the `buildHeader` function.

Comment: i added a `if-else` in the `buildHeader` function that I forgot to add, and I put `lastPromise.done(...)` outside the loop.  if the `else` is never hit, and `lastPromise` never set get, will `lastPromise` still resolve?  It is working in my app, but I'm wondering if this will cause some undesired behavior.

Comment: @RobM `lastPromise` can't resolve it never gets set as a promise.  You'd need to do another `if-else` statement to check if `lastPromise` is set.  I'll add an edit to my post with an example.